# Concatenate Django urls with parameters as href

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I got a template where i send a queryset of this model:

```
class ShopItems(Base):

    name = models.CharField('Item name', max_length = 150)
    url  = models.CharField('url', max_length = 200)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

With this data:

```
Id  name      Url
1   "Sales"    "{% url shop:sales product.id %}"
2   "Payroll"   "{% url shop:payroll area.id type.id %}"
.
.
. And so on...
```

In that template i need to iterate this model items setting each item url as a href, as you can see each url it's different and receive a diferent ammount of parameters, so, i defined the url field in the model as a string and try it:

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
        {% for item in items  %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                <td><a href="{{ item.url }}">Go</a></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Of course, i send product, area and type via context from the view too.

But it doesn't work, already tried also:

> href={{ item.url }} -- with no ""

And concatenating the url removing the parameters from the string in the model field to use it like this then:

href= "{{ item.url }} + product.id"

Any idea ?, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the model of the item? Otherwise it will be hard to tell what is wrong. And it should be with the "".

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing here. Are you storing the string `{% shop:sales product.id %}` in the database? Why?

Comment: Jostcrow I've added the model. @Daniel Roseman yes, i know it may not be the best way, but as each item has a different url and may receive different parameters i didn't found another way so far, any suggestion ?

Comment: Well, even if this could be made to work, there is no template tag `{% shop:sales %}`. Did you perhaps mean `{% url "shop:sales" product.id %}`? (Not that this will work as is either, but at least it's a valid tag.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman Right, actually it is as you said and in my model it's ok, i corrected my typo in the question. Thing is, what could be a better way to solve this without burning the urls in the model due that may be new items with different urls and different parameters ?